# how to find all negative weight cycles(elementary circuit) in a strongly connected directed graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs

I can use Bellman-Ford to get some of the elementary negative weight cycles in a graph. It's not guaranteed to always get all of them.

(Elementary Cycle: A cycle is elementary if no vertex but the first and last appears twice.)

But I want to find *ALL* elementary negative weight cycles. Even taking each vertex as the source will not always get *ALL* negative weight cycles.

Take this graph for example:

[image]

With Bellman-Ford, starting from any vertex, I can only get one cycle "U→H→U".

The cycle "U→S→U" is always missing.

Is there any algorithm with which I can find all negative weight cycles reliably?

Comment: (I needed three attempts to understand $A$ until I concluded that you probably want to emphasise *exactly **one***.) If there is more than one *negative weight cycle*, what *is* `the elementary circuit`?

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for your comments. How about this version? Is it more clear now?

Comment: *I* do think so - let me try and give a hand.

Comment: You might get a _lot_ of cycles: for example in a complete graph on $n$ vertices, where all edge weights are negative, you would get something like $n!$ elementary cycles. Do you want to impose some kind of disjointness condition on the output cycles?

Answer (score 1):

My current strategy is:

1. first enumerate all elementary cycles. I use the hawick algorithm which is already implemented in the c++ boost library.
2. sum all the weights of edges in each cycle and then check if the sum is negative.